# Updating field gets duplicate entry for primary key, so I want to delete

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm modifying 2 million rows with a statement like this:

```
UPDATE table SET fieldname=REPLACE(fieldname,'APS','')
```

The error is:

```
#1062 - Duplicate entry 'asdsads' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

How do I run this command, and then any rows that are duplicate, just delete them?

Comment: Is the fieldname used a PK?

Comment: @WickedFan yes, it is

Comment: By definition, a PK field needs to be unique. Does the field have an identity set to it? Is there another PK field in the table? Is there any FK linking to them?

Comment: Please specify the full-fledged primary key of `table` - otherwise this will become a very abstract discussion...

Comment: @WickedFan I know it has to be unique. That's why I want to delete the updated key if the key already exists. There are no other PKs or PK links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do is easy:

**1) remove primary key**

```
ALTER TABLE `yourTable`
DROP PRIMARY KEY;
```

**2) update the table**

```
UPDATE yourTable SET fieldname=REPLACE(fieldname,'APS','');
```

**3) create a new primary key with IGNORE - that remove duplications**

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `yourTable` 
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`fieldname `);
```

Comment: I'm trying to drop the primary key, but it's been running for 10 minutes.

Comment: it depending on your server and server config and you have  2 million rows in the table.

Comment: @User - I have create a test table on my Mac Nook DROP and CREATE the PRIMARY KEY. My table has 2.000.000 row and its take 13 sec. each

Comment: @User - How long has it use to do the changes on your server ?